# Getting Could not load the framework 'IDEFoundation' while running Xamarin form application

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio, xcode8

I'm getting the following error while running Xamarin form application. I've installed Xcode-beta 8. Can anyone please help?

```
Failed to launch the simulator: Could not load the framework 'IDEFoundation' (path: /Users/apple/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/IDEFoundation): dlopen(/Users/apple/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/IDEFoundation, 1): Library not loaded: @rpath/DVTDocumentation.framework/Versions/A/DVTDocumentation
  Referenced from: /Users/apple/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/IDEFoundation
  Reason: image not found
error MT1008: Failed to launch the simulator: Could not load the framework 'IDEFoundation' (path: /Users/apple/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/IDEFoundation): dlopen(/Users/apple/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/IDEFoundation, 1): Library not loaded: @rpath/DVTDocumentation.framework/Versions/A/DVTDocumentation
  Referenced from: /Users/apple/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/IDEFoundation
  Reason: image not found
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Xcode 7.3 instead, the stable version of Xamarin Studio / Xamarin.iOS does not support unstable versions of Xcode.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I reverted Xcode version and it seems working.

Comment: Even with a stable version I've hit this issue :(

Comment: @Le-roy: what's the complete version information for Xamarin Studio (in the About menu click on Show Details)?

Comment: @RolfBjarneKvinge

Version 6.1.2 (build 44)
Runtime:
 Mono 4.6.2 (mono-4.6.0-branch/08fd525) (64-bit)
 GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

 Package version: 406020007

=== NuGet ===
Version: 3.4.3.0

=== Apple Dev Tools ===
Xcode 8.1 (11544)
Build 8B62

=== Xamarin.iOS ===
Version: 10.2.1.5 (Xamarin Studio Community)
Hash: 44931ae
Branch: xcode8.1
Build date: 2016-11-01 20:52:28-0400

=== Build Information ===
Release ID: 601020044
Build date: 2016-10-28 15:12:43-04
Build lane: monodevelop-lion-cycle8

Comment: @Le-roy: that should definitely work. If you file a bug (http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) we'll help you diagnose and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like some part of Xamarin's tools is trying to use reverse-engineered internal components of Xcode for its own purposes. That's not supported by Xcode, and is something Xamarin will need to address.